# Regular expression to match a string and some letters

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regular expression for a Flex program that would match a "string "  and a sequence of letters that exist in the range `[A-E]`.

What i m trying to do is get the cases that the input has the "string " and either 1 or 2 or 4 or more than 4 letters that exist in the range [A-E].**<

What i have tried so far is the regular expression: `"string "([A-E]{1,2}|[A-E]{4,})`
The case that the letters are in the range {4,} obviously works however the case {1,2} doesn't since if the user gives into the input "string "ABC it will invoke the case [A-E]{1,2}.

I thought about using a regular expression with a NOT operator something along the lines of : `"string "(NOT OPERATOR)([A-E]{3})` so that i would be getting every case that the "string " is followed by anything else that 3 letters, but it turns out there is not such operator.

What can i do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any answer given!

Comment: Looks like `"string "([A-E]{1,2}|[A-E]{4,})\b` might work.

Comment: What about this string `"string "ABZ` should it match or not? If it should not, then boundary condition will not work.

Comment: All this is part of an excersise and it is assumed that the user wont type any letter other than the ones in range [A-E].So we know that ABZ will never be a given input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the string "ABC" matches `[A-E]{1,2}` because you don't insist that those letters are the *only* thing in the specified string (hence, "AB" matches and "C" just gets lumped in there for some other reason). You should insist that when the regex is done, you've reached the end of the line/string:

```
^string ([A-E]{1,2}|[A-E]{4})$
```

or at least some sort of word boundary:

```
string ([A-E]{1,2}|[A-E]{4})\b
```